# BASH script to *create* filenames with spaces from filenames with "%20"

Tags: regex, bash, filenames, spaces

First, I know this sounds ass backwards.  It is.  But I'm looking to convert (on the BASH command line) a bunch of script-generated thumbnail filenames that *do* have a "%20" in them to the equivalent without filenames.  In case you're curious, the reason is because the script I'm using created the thumbnail filenames from their current URLs, and it added the %20 in the process.  But now WordPress is looking for files like "This%20Filename.jpg" and the browser is, of course, removing the escape character and replacing it with spaces.  Which is why one shouldn't have spaces in filenames.

But since I'm stuck here, I'd love to convert my existing thumbnails over.  Next, I will post a question for help fixing the problem in the script mentioned above.  What I'm looking for now is a quick script to do the bad thing and create filenames with spaces out of filenames with "%20"s.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you *only* want to replace each literal `%20` with one space:

```
for i in *; do
    mv "$i" "${i//\%20/ }"
done
```

(for instance this will rename `file%with%20two%20spaces` to `file%with two spaces`). 
You'll probably need to apply `%25`->`%` too though, and other similar transforms.

Answer (score 2):

`convmv` can do this, no script needed.

```
$ ls
a%20b.txt
$ convmv --unescape *.txt --notest
mv "./a%20b.txt"    "./a b.txt"
Ready!
$ ls
a b.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

personally, I don't like file names with spaces - beware you will have to treat them specially in future scripts. Anyway, here is the script that will do what you want to achieve.

```
#!/bin/sh
for fname in `ls *%20*`
do
  newfname=`echo $fname | sed 's/%20/ /g'`
  mv $fname "$newfname"
done;
```

Place this to a file, add execute permission and run this from the directory where you have file with %20 in their names.

Comment: this worked great.  Thank you and please know that I agree with your sentiment.  I don't like having filenames with spaces either.  In fact, perhaps you can help with my attempt at a permanent solution, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849614/php-regex-script-to-create-filenames-with-dashes-instead-of-spaces

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is where your files currently are
DPATH="/home/you/foo/*.txt"

# This is where your new files will be created
BPATH="/home/you/new_foo" 

TFILE="/tmp/out.tmp.$$"
[ ! -d $BPATH ] && mkdir -p $BPATH || :
for f in $DPATH
do
  if [ -f $f -a -r $f ]; then
    /bin/cp -f $f $BPATH
   sed "s/%20/ /g" "$f" > $TFILE && mv $TFILE "$f"
  else
   echo "Error: Cannot read $f"
  fi
done
/bin/rm $TFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not bash, but for the more general case of %hh (encoded hex) in names.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
foreach $c(@ARGV){
    $d=$c;
    $d=~s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/my $a=pack('C',hex($1));$a="\\$a"/eg;
    print `mv $c $d` if ($c ne $d);
}
```