# PHP/regex : Script to create filenames with dashes instead of spaces

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, filenames, spaces

I want to amend a PHP script I'm using in wordPress (Auto Featured Image plugin).
The problem is that this script creates filenames for thumbnails based on the URLs of the image.

That sounds great until you get a filename with spaces and the thumbnail is something like `this%20Thumbnail.jpg` and when the browser goes to `http://www.whatever.com/this%20Thumbnail.jpg` it converts the `%20` to a space and there is no filename on the server by that name (with spaces).

To fix this, I *think* I need to change the following line in such a way that $imageURL is filtered to convert `%20` to spaces.  Sound right?
Here is the code. Perhaps you can tell me if I'm barking up the wrong tree.
Thank you!

```
<?php
  static function create_post_attachment_from_url($imageUrl = null)
  {
      if(is_null($imageUrl)) return null;
      // get file name
      $filename = substr($imageUrl, (strrpos($imageUrl, '/'))+1);
      if (!(($uploads = wp_upload_dir(current_time('mysql')) ) && false === $uploads['error'])) {
          return null;
      }
      // Generate unique file name
      $filename = wp_unique_filename( $uploads['path'], $filename );
?>
```

Comment: What about _other_ characters?

Comment: @salman-a - what other characters are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Edited to a more appropriate and complete answer:

```
static function create_post_attachment_from_url($imageUrl = null)
{
    if(is_null($imageUrl)) return null;

    // get the original filename from the URL
    $filename = substr($imageUrl, (strrpos($imageUrl, '/'))+1);

    // this bit is not relevant to the question, but we'll leave it in
    if (!(($uploads = wp_upload_dir(current_time('mysql')) ) && false === $uploads['error'])) {
        return null;
    }

    // Sanitize the filename we extracted from the URL
    // Replace any %-escaped character with a dash
    $filename = preg_replace('/%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}/', '-', $filename);

    // Let Wordpress further modify the filename if it may clash with 
    // an existing one in the same directory
    $filename = wp_unique_filename( $uploads['path'], $filename );

    // ...
}
```

Comment: am I wrong in assuming that the problem is not with the line you're describing but with line 5 in my code sample?  I thank you for your response but I don't think it answers my question.  Thank you!

Comment: I think your issue is not completely clear to me: are you trying to solve a bug or just fixing the minor inconvenience of having escaped %20 sequences in the filename of the saved thumbnail? As far as I can tell, the script takes the URL from an image from the Internet, fetch the content and save that image on disk to create an attachment in Wordpress. I've edited the code to remove any escaped character (like spaces, symbols, etc) from the original image file name and replace these characters by dashes.

Comment: $filename = preg_replace('/%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}/', '-', $filename); - this line saved my life! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You better to replace the spaces in image name with underscores or hypens using regexp.

```
$string = "Google%20%20%20Search%20Amit%20Singhal"
preg_replace('/%20+/g', ' ', $string);
```

This regex will replace multiple spaces (%20) with a single space(' ').

Comment: codef0rmer - I don't understand your response.  I'm not looking to replace spaces, per se.  Maybe I wasn't clear with my question.  I want to modify the above script, which gets the filenames as URLs with %20 substituted for spaces, with a script that takes those filenames that have %20 in them and replaces the %20s with dashes.

Comment: I think when you upload an image, it does not replace spaces with some characters (eg. underscore or hypen) and the image url has %20 chars replacing spaces which you do not want. 

My suggestion would be to replace spaces with underscore/hypen while you upload an image instead of parsing %20 later. 

Anyways, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I believe the that regex is wrong: `/%20+/` should be `/(%20)+/`, otherwise, you only replace stuff like `%20` and `%200`, `%2000`, etc. Beside, the `+` should not be necessary, and the `g` modifier is not valid, if I'm not mistaken, `preg_replace` replaces all occurrences in the string anyway.